# Delayed update of javafx custom control

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, java-8

I need specific behaviour when my custom control resized. When control resized(resize or resizeRelocate methods called) first I want just scale child nodes to fit new bounds. And if there is no size changes in i.e. 1 second - make expensive calculations and relayout of child nodes. If I recalculate on every resize call - it makes Stage resizing very laggy. How can I achieve that?

This is example, here `CurvePlot` is just data model:

```
class ShapeCurvePlot extends Polyline {
    private final CurvePlot model;

    public ShapeCurvePlot(CurvePlot model) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(model);
        this.model = model;
        strokeProperty().bind(model.strokeProperty());
        strokeWidthProperty().bind(model.strokeWidthProperty());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isResizable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(double width, double height) {
        // "expensive calculation"
        Series series = model.getSeries();
        double xOffset = series.valueAxis().getLeft();
        double yOffset = series.keyAxis().getLeft();
        double yScale = height / series.keyAxis().range();
        double xScale = width / series.valueAxis().range();

        getPoints().clear();
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> item : series.data().entrySet()) {
            double x = item.getValue();
            double y = item.getKey();
            getPoints().addAll((x - xOffset) * xScale, (y - yOffset) * yScale);
        }
    }
}
```

While in this example resize works fast, other shapes, that I need, not so easy to recalculate. I'm  asking for generic solution to delay calculation until there was no resizing within X seconds.

ps. sorry for my english, I'm not native speaker..

Comment: Try to reframe your question, add some snippets and make it simple ! I am unable to understand your question !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, updated with example code. I need to recalculate shapes instead of scaling to keep strokeWidth fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this issue before, both in C# and Java. My solution, not saying that it is the best solution, but it seems to work, is to use some form of timer that triggers the expensive re-calculation.

In my situation, I have used this in search text boxes, the actual search is only triggered after the user has not pressed a key for some time (say 500ms), preventing the triggering of the search for every key stroke.

In your situation, you could trigger the timer within the resize() method. When the timer runs out, it then performs the expensive operation. Triggering the timer while it is already waiting results in the timer being reset.

In java I did this by using a java.util.Timer for the timer which would then run a java.util.TimerTask that I created. Within the run() method of the TimerTask, I created a javafx.concurrent.Task and ran that in a new Thread. The call() method of the Task is where the work was done. This ensured that the work was done on the JavaFX thread, otherwise you get threading issues.

Hopefully this is some help to you.

Edit ... here's some code that should do what I was talking about above. *Note: This code is completely untested, I think it should work though*

```
class ShapeCurvePlot extends Polyline {
private class ResizeTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private ShapeCurvePlot plot;

    public ResizeTimerTask(ShapeCurvePlot plot) {
        this.plot = plot;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.util.TimerTask#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Task<Object> t = new Task<Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                // "expensive calculation"
                Series series = plot.getSeries();
                double xOffset = series.valueAxis().getLeft();
                double yOffset = series.keyAxis().getLeft();
                double yScale = height / series.keyAxis().range();
                double xScale = width / series.valueAxis().range();

                plot.getPoints().clear();
                for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> item : series.data().entrySet()) {
                    double x = item.getValue();
                    double y = item.getKey();
                    plot.getPoints().addAll((x - xOffset) * xScale, (y - yOffset) * yScale);
                }
            }
        }

        new Thread(t).start();
    }
}

private static int RESIZE_DELAY_MS = 1000;
private final CurvePlot model;
private Timer resizeTimer;

public ShapeCurvePlot(CurvePlot model) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(model);
    this.model = model;
    strokeProperty().bind(model.strokeProperty());
    strokeWidthProperty().bind(model.strokeWidthProperty());
}

@Override
public boolean isResizable() {
    return true;
}

public Series getSeries() {
    return this.model.getSeries();
}

@Override
public void resize(double width, double height) {
    // cancel the current task (if any).
    if(this.resizeTimer != null) {
        this.resizeTimer.cancel();
        this.resizeTimer.purge();
        this.resizeTimer = null;
    }

    try {
        // create a new task that will be executed in 1 second.
        this.resizeTimer = new Timer();
        this.resizeTimer.schedule(new ResizeTimerTask(this), RESIZE_DELAY_MS);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        oom.printStackTrace();
        if(this.resizeTimer != null) {
            this.resizeTimer.cancel();
            this.resizeTimer.purge();
            this.resizeTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Further Edit ... Just spent some of today playing with JavaFX threading issues, there is another option that you could use for running the time consuming task in the JavaFX display thread. Rather than using a Task, you could execute a Runnable in the JavaFX thread using javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Runnable r). This will execute the runnable some time in the future, with the benefit that all runnables that are run in this way are processed in FIFO order. This can be handy to prevent things from getting out of order while still being able to run them in an async manner on the JavaFX display thread.

To do that, you would change the implementation of the run() method of the ResizeTimerTask class to:

```
public void run() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                // "expensive calculation"
            Series series = plot.getSeries();
            double xOffset = series.valueAxis().getLeft();
            double yOffset = series.keyAxis().getLeft();
            double yScale = height / series.keyAxis().range();
            double xScale = width / series.valueAxis().range();

            plot.getPoints().clear();
            for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> item : series.data().entrySet()) {
                double x = item.getValue();
                double y = item.getKey();
                plot.getPoints().addAll((x - xOffset) * xScale, (y - yOffset) * yScale);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no probs, hope it works well for you. I just added an alternate implemenation using Platform.runLater() that should work too.